# Show tooltip once page initialized - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tooltip

I need to show a hint/tooltip for the userto indicate the user can get his current location by pressing the button. Have included the **Tooltip** in the code but only when the user does a long press of the button the tooltip is appearing, i want the tooltip to appear when the screen is initialized.

Code:

```
  GlobalKey _toolTipKey = GlobalKey();
GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        final dynamic tooltip = _toolTipKey.currentState;
                        tooltip.ensureTooltipVisible();
                      },
                      child: Tooltip(
                        key: _toolTipKey,
                        message: 'Get current Location',
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 30,
                          child: IconButton(
                            onPressed: getLocation,
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.my_location,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use Statefulwidget and in initState write below code

```
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        // Flutter get callback here when screen initialized.
        final dynamic tooltip = _toolTipKey.currentState;
        tooltip.ensureTooltipVisible();

    });
  }
```

---

Here the Full Source code When you run the app it directly shows "Get current Location" tooltip

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GlobalKey _toolTipKey = GlobalKey();


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      // Flutter get callback here when screen initialized.
      final dynamic tooltip = _toolTipKey.currentState;
      tooltip.ensureTooltipVisible();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Tooltip(
              key: _toolTipKey,
              message: 'Get current Location',
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 30,
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.my_location,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The method 'ensureTooltipVisible' was called on null.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to implement the same thing and I after lot of trying I managed to get it working.

You can use stateful widget and call the function to show tooltip in its initState. Now I got the same error as another person.
The method `ensureTooltipVisible` was called on null.
To solve this, I had to call

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10));
```

before `ensureTooltipVisible()` function.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    showTooltipIfOnboadingComplete();
  }
```

and the function to show and close tooltip after certain amount of time,

```
Future showAndCloseTooltip() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10));
    tooltipkey.currentState.ensureTooltipVisible();
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4));
    tooltipkey.currentState.deactivate();
  }
```

you will also have to set you Tooltip widget trigger mode as TooltipTriggerMode.manual,
Here is complete code;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const FloatingSupportButton()
    );
  }
}

class FloatingSupportButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const FloatingSupportButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FloatingSupportButton> createState() => _FloatingSupportButtonState();
}

class _FloatingSupportButtonState extends State<FloatingSupportButton> {
  // final GlobalKey<TooltipState> tooltipkey = GlobalKey<TooltipState>();
  final tooltipkey = GlobalKey<State<Tooltip>>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    showAndCloseTooltip();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Tooltip(
          message: "Hello",
          triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.manual,
          key: tooltipkey,
          preferBelow: false,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            shape: const CircleBorder(
              side: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFc60c0c),
            onPressed: () {
              showAndCloseTooltip();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future showAndCloseTooltip() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10));
    // tooltipkey.currentState.ensureTooltipVisible();
    final dynamic tooltip = tooltipkey.currentState;
    tooltip?.ensureTooltipVisible();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4));
    // tooltipkey.currentState.deactivate();
    tooltip?.deactivate();
  }
}
```

Have a great day everyone, hope this was helpful !!